# Should I pick a linear model that has a higher F-Value or lower number of variables used?

Tags: r, regression, anova, feature-selection, f-test

My first model:

```
Residual standard error: 6010 on 1324 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7561,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7537 
F-statistic: 315.7 on 13 and 1324 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

My second model:

```
Residual standard error: 6014 on 1328 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7551,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7534 
F-statistic: 454.9 on 9 and 1328 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Since the F values are what stick out to me, personally, it's what I'd like to ask about.
Would it be best to go with the first or the second model?

Here is my ANOVA 'chi' test result:

````
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: charges ~ age + sex + bmi + children + smoker + region + age_category + 
    weight_condition
Model 2: charges ~ age + bmi + children + smoker + age_category + weight_condition
  Res.Df        RSS Df  Sum of Sq Pr(>Chi)
1   1324 4.7820e+10                       
2   1328 4.8025e+10 -4 -205278282   0.2241
```
````

Comment: Since the R value is nearly the same.  It doesn’t appear the extra values are adding much value.  The anova has a p value of .22.  I would chose the simpler model.

Comment: @Dave2e so does that mean that the ANOVA process doesn't add anything, then? Still choose the second model despite it having a p value  that's high at 0.2241?

Comment: I think the ANOVA is comparing model1 to model2 and the high p value is indicating that there is not a difference between the 2 models.

Comment: What is the goal of your regression? Keep in mind that, whenever you do this kind of model selection, you affect your downstream inferences. There are good and less-than-good ways to account for that.

Comment: What are you picking the model for?

Comment: @Roland. For best prediction.

Comment: Then you should optimize for out of sample predictions. Usually, that means splitting the data into calibration and validation data and doing cross-validation with the calibration data for model selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer certainly depends on your research question as @Roland suggests, but if you want to understand which model fits the data best, generally you want to compute BIC or AIC (in R there are many packages doing so, for example [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/rcompanion/man/compareGLM.html)). In this case I would also bet the simpler model (model 2) will work better, i.e. have a smaller AIC and BIC, because the variance explained by the more complicated model (model 1) is not much higher.

Comment: Could you explain why BIC/AIC is a better determining factor?

Comment: the F values you reported compare the null model (charges ~1 in R notation) with models 1-2, respectively. they do not compare model 1 with model 2. comparing the 2 F-values does not tell you which model fits the data better (i.e. without overfitting). you could compute F-values to compare the two models, see: https://sites.duke.edu/bossbackup/files/2013/02/FTestTutorial.pdf . I expect using BIC or AIC would give a similar answer.